# android intent filter for pick file not working on Huawei P8 and LG F70 phones

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want to open *.gpx files with my app. After some resource I placed these intent filters to my manifest file:

```
<!-- Intent-filter for Intents that contain the file suffix. -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <!--  For a path to be meaningful, both a scheme and an authority must be specified. -->
    <data
        android:host="*"
        android:mimeType="*/*"
        android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx"
        android:scheme="file"/>
</intent-filter>

<!-- Intent-filter for Intents that contain a MIME type -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <!-- This is the original mimeType which was used when creating the file. -->
    <data android:mimeType="application/gpx+xml"/>

    <!-- Some apps (e.g. some versions of Gmail) use the file suffix as the mimeType! -->
    <data android:mimeType="application/gpx"/>
</intent-filter>

<!-- Gmail sometimes uses some strange mimeTypes when opening attachments -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data
        android:scheme="content"
        android:host="gmail-ls"
        android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and it's works with the most of android versions and phones.

BUT as far as I know on the LG F70 with android version 4.4.2 and on the Huawei P8 Lite with android version 5.0.1 using the default file browsers it's not working. See the pictures:

Huawei P8 Lite:
[image: Huawei P8 Lite]

LG F70:

[image: LG F70]

Does anyone experienced this before? Do you have any idea which intent filter would I need? 
Any answer would be really apprechiated!

Comment: What is **application/gpx**, is it a known mime type?

Comment: Yes, it is a type of XML: http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp. But this is not the point I think, you should be able to define an intent filter for a totally new mime type also I think.

Comment: There are only standard mime types: http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java.  It is not possible to define your own!

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't agree with you. MIME only defines a format (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) and anything that matches that format can be a valid MIME type. Android defines the most common MIME types for you but anyone can define his own, the operating system is flexible enough to handle it.

Comment: Can  you show me an example in AndroidManifest that works with your custom MIME type extension?  My answer below covers many MIME types, but it won't cover your one type alone...

Comment: Mine in the question works with the most of the android phones and tablets (including the nexus and pixel phones, which should be the standard, I think). Excluding only the above few examples, where the specific application (the default file browser written by the manufacturer) handles the opening as they open the unknown formats as PDF or not open them at all (so they are not using intents correctly). If I use an another application on the above two phones the opening works for gpx as it should be.

Comment: Android runs on thousands of phone models.  So most people do not have nexus and pixel.  There is no **standard**, as you say.  Hence your problem.  Give my solution below a try...

Comment: I'm sorry, but it was a company code, and I don't have access to it any more, neater the phones, so I won't be able to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `<intent-filter>` should be meaningless on all devices, as you cannot have `android:host` without `android:scheme`.

Either:

- Remove the `android:host` attribute, or
- Move that particular `<data>` element into its own `<intent-filter>`, with a copy of the relevant actions/categories, and with an `android:scheme` of `content`

The difference between the two is whether you want to try handling `application/octet-stream` from any source (first bullet) or only from Gmail's content provider (second bullet).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I have modified my question as you have suggested, but it still does not work on the above two phones. :(

Comment: @bendaf: Probably they are using a `Uri` that has a different MIME type, one which is not matching your middle `<intent-filter>`. Temporarily change that `<intent-filter>` (or add a new one) that supports a MIME type of `*/*`. If you get control, examine the MIME type of the `Intent` that they are using. Then, use that information to update your middle `<intent-filter>` to handle those apps (or, if they are using something too generic, like `application/octet-stream`, settle for not being able to support those file managers).

Comment: I have very strange experiences. I did the modifications that you have suggested, so both phones offer my app for opening .apk files also for example, but for the .gpx format they still showing the same error toast. It means that I will not be able to support these file managers, right? (I also tried to rename the *.gpx file to *.apk and the file manager offered my app as  I would expect, but if I rename it back to *.gpx it's still not working.)

Comment: @bendaf: At this point, I have no idea how further to debug this. Sorry!

Comment: @bendaf It's important to test with gmail attachments named '.nevermatch' or something else that nothing should open. A lot of the solutions posted on the Internet will open all file types and ignore the pathPattern

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track there with your initial code.  Here is how you can make it work:

```
        <!-- Handle opening attachments with file explorer -->
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="*" android:mimeType="application/xml"
                  android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="*"
                  android:mimeType="*/*"
                  android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Handle opening attachments with Downloads app -->
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/xml" android:pathPattern=".*\.gpx"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\.gpx"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/xml" android:pathPattern=".*\.gpx"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\.gpx"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Handle opening attachments with Gmail -->
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <data android:host="gmail-ls" android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <data android:host="gmail-ls" android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <data android:host="gmail-ls" android:mimeType="application/xml"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <data android:host="gmail-ls" android:mimeType="application/xml"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

The key here is to handle proper MIME types and categories, and presume various ways of opening files on devices (i.e. file browsers, downloads app, gmail, etc.).